# Loading Nib Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5, nib

I'm working in Xcode 4.3.2.

I'm trying to load a Nib programmatically instead of using Storyboards. Storyboards seems a lot simpler, but unfortunately they are not compatible with iOS 4 & I'm building an application that requires backwards compatibility.

Here's my problem: I'm trying to load the main view - a simple view with a green background. Currently there is no default view.

My files are:

AppDelegate.h/.m
GreenViewController.h/.m
SwitchViewController.h/.m

I want to the green screen to load when the app begins so in AppDelegate.m I have:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.switchViewController = [[SwitchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GreenView" bundle:nil];

    //UIView *switchView = self.switchViewController.view;


    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

In SwitchViewController.m I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.greenViewController = [[GreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GreenView" bundle:nil];
    [self.view insertSubview:self.greenViewController.view atIndex:0];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

With the simple initWithNibName filled in with the default code.

In GreenViewController.m I have:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

Here is the main functionality of everything. When I run the app, I immediately get the error:

```
2012-10-09 12:34:35.586 MyViewSwitcher[5210:f803] -[AppDelegate setSwitchViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c6c310
2012-10-09 12:34:35.587 MyViewSwitcher[5210:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate setSwitchViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c6c310'
```

Can someone please help me understand the cause of my error? I made sure the the "Custom Class" of the GreenView.xib is the "GreenViewController" in the Identity Inspector. Also, I made sure that the referencing outlet for "View" was the file's owner. I want to load the GreenView nib when my app launches. Eventually, I will switch views by adding a button, but so far I haven't been able to even load the main view. I'm not sure what I'm misunderstanding.

Thank you in advance for you help!

Comment: do you have synthesized your `switchViewController` property properly?

Comment: Adil, that was definitely my problem. I added "@synthesize switchViewController;" & now my error is: 2012-10-09 13:48:27.970 MyViewSwitcher[5345:f803] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

Comment: Could you give me hand with this? I think I'm getting on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with loading the nib.  The problem is on this line:

```
self.switchViewController = [[SwitchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GreenView" bundle:nil];
```

Here you are using “dot syntax“, which is explained in [*The Objective-C Programming Language*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW17).  When you set a property using that syntax, the compiler transforms it into a regular Objective-C message like this:

```
[self setSwitchViewController:[[SwitchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GreenView" bundle:nil]];
```

At runtime, the system is telling you that your `AppDelegate` object doesn't understand the `setSwitchViewController:` method.  You need to use an `@synthesize` directive, which is explained in [*The Objective-C Programming Language*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW9), to tell the compiler to implement the `setSwitchViewController:` method for you:

```
@synthesize switchViewController = _switchViewController;
```

Comment: A clean & build helped too. Thank you Rob.

Answer (score 0):

```
 '-[AppDelegate setSwitchViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c6c310'
```

You are sending the message (calling the method) `setSwitchViewController:` to/in your AppDelegate. That's the issue.

Comment: How am I calling the method setSwitchViewController? I haven't defined it. Am I calling it implicitly somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

1. Please make sure your `UIWindow` has `rootViewController`, before using `makeKeyAndVisible`

   [self.window setRootViewController:self.switchViewController];
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
2. Make sure properties are synthesized, as instructed above.
3. When implementing methods in subclass, like your `SwitchViewController.m`, when to call `super` methods is important. Unless there is any special intention of yours, almost always calling `super` implementation precedes local `self` implementation. So, I suggest you to change `- (void)viewDidLoad` in `SwitchViewController.m` to be like following

   - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     self.greenViewController = [[GreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GreenView" bundle:nil];

     [self.view insertSubview:self.greenViewController.view atIndex:0];
     }